# How do you say "make out" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, solicitud-de-modismo, sexualidad

To make out means to kiss.

But not just a quick peck on the cheek. Or even a single French kiss.

To make out means to like have a session of kissing usually with the intent of fore-play...

How do you say that in Spanish?

Comment: This is an interesting question but you should specify which flavour of Spanish you would like the answers to address. As an example, in Spain we say "darse el lote" with a similar meaning, but I don't know if that is used in any of the American Spanish countries.

Comment: probablemente una respuesta para el comunity wiki

Comment: This needs a region tag or else is too broad

Answer (score 8):

In Spanish we have a colloquial expression that is **darse/pegarse el lote con alquien.**

> [**darse**, o **pegarse**, alguien **el lote**](https://dle.rae.es/lote)
>
> 1. locs. verbs. malsons. Besuquearse y manosearse con otra persona.

The RAE's dictionary records it as "malsonante" (vulgarism) but I think it's more a colloquialism than a vulgarism.

You also have **[morrearse](https://dle.rae.es/morrear?m=form)** (o darse un morreo):

> 1. tr. vulg. Besar a alguien en la boca de forma insistente o prolongada. U. m. c. prnl.

Depending on the context, you could also use **enrollarse con alguien**. While *enrollarse con alguien* could have several meanings, the [eighth acceptation](https://dle.rae.es/enrollar?m=form) includes the meaning of *to have a loving or sexual relationship or to have an affaire with someone*

> 8. prnl. coloq. Entablar una relación amorosa o erótica, normalmente pasajera. Se ha enrollado CON alguien mayor que él.

With the appropiate context you could use *enrollarse* to convey "making out".

> Cada noche que sales te enrollas con un tío/tía distinto!

Of course *enrollarse* could mean to do more than just kissing, so it could be very context-dependent.

Comment: el darse/pegarse con el lote es españolismo... al menos en Colombia no recuerdo haberla oído y no lo tengo presente en libros, programas de televisión (quizá por vulgarismo) o en canciones (más amplias a los vulgarismos en ciertos géneros)

Comment: I would also suggest "liarse con alguien", which is common in Spain with the same meaning as "enrollarse con alguien"

Comment: Sorry, this is very much related to a region, imho this is not a proper answer.

Comment: @VeAqui para mi ninguna cuadra para Colombia. Todas me suenan a España únicamente.

Answer (score 6):

The main verb is

> besar

but has many local slang variations depending on the country and region:

:: **Argentina**

- chapar
- transar
- comer[se la boca]

:: **México**

- se faja (o se da un faje).

Comment: A Mexican boy I know always uses “comer” to mean sucking on something other than lips.... I’d be super careful with that.

Comment: In México, "to make out" is **fajar** and the action of making out is **un faje**. https://dem.colmex.mx/Ver/fajar

Comment: A bit old-fashioned now, maybe, but **apretar** is another Argentinian way of saying this. Totally agree with the other three.